# Group records in a report

Tags: ms-access, vba

This script filters  records based on user input (Startdate and enddate) from a prior screen.  It works properly, but I want the outputted report to group the data by another field, [SN].  How would I add that parameter?

```
Me.Filter = "[Date] between #" & Format(Me!startdate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") 
& "# and #" & Format(Me!enddate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# "
 strFilter = Me.Filter

Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.OpenReport "Monthly Ops", acViewReport, , Me.Filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can dynamically 'group by' in Access reports. Assuming you have a limited number of fields that you might want to group by, I would create that number of different reports, each with one of the different grouping options, and then use your other parameter to determine which report to open.

Comment: if not in the report itself, is there a way to use a query?

Comment: Not easily; grouping is a feature of the report that sits on top of the underlying query. You could possibly use the parameter to set a global variable, and then your query could have a column that returns one of your potential grouping fields depending on the value of that variable (you need to write a function to get the variable's value from within the query). Your report could then group by that new column in the query.

Comment: The multiple reports option would give you greater flexibility over what you could put in the group header/footer for the different grouping fields.

Answer (score 0):

The Access Report Wizard give the option of grouping on one or more fields.  I was able to group on SN and sort by date, and I think I will filter using a query prior to sending records to the report.